# Can anticholinergics like benztropine be used to treat Catatonia?

Tags: psychiatry, psychopharmacology, drugs, pharmacopsychiatry

I found an [old paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2018827/) describing a case study where a catatonic patient was successfully treated with benztropine (Cogentin). However, I can't find any modern guidelines that calls for this treatment (first-line is usually benzodiazepams). Is there any reason not to use anticholinergics for catatonia treatment?

Sources:

1. Albucher RC, DeQuardo J, Tandon R. Treatment of catatonia with an anticholinergic agent. Biol Psychiatry. 1991;29(5):513-514. doi:10.1016/0006-3223(91)90281-p
2. Francis A. Catatonia: diagnosis, classification, and treatment. Curr Psychiatry Rep 2010; 12:180.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anticholinergics by themselves commonly have sedative effects. The reason you read about benztropine being used is that it has dopaminergic activity as well (in addition to anticholinergic activity). Specifically, [benztropine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzatropine) and its derivatives are also dopamine reuptake inhibitors.

So from the perspective that benztropine is a dopamine reuptake inhibitor, i.e. a stimulant in the traditional sense, it would probably be a bad idea to use as a treatment for catatonia. If I remember right, its particular binding affinity is significant at the dopamine transporter.